# Entity Framework Core receiving 0 for seeding as Id although I defined it to be something else

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

When trying to add a migration, ef core gives me the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'MyEntity' cannot be added because a
> non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a
> negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.

Entity MyEntity and its superclass/interface:

```
public class MyEntity: EntityObject
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<StateChange> StateChanges { get; set; }
}

public class EntityObject : IEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class IEntityObject
{
    int Id { get; set; 
    byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Seeding:

```
 var seed = new MyEntity{ Id = -2, StateChanges = new List<StateChange>(), OrderId = -2 };
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasData(seed);
```

I have been trying various things with the [Key] and [DatabaseGenerated] but could not find a solution.
The version of all the ef core nuget dependencies is 3.1.5

Comment: Any reason why you are setting the id and orderid to -2. Did you check by providing positive values?

Comment: Yes, I did try that too

Comment: I see.  I would also comment the hasdata method and check once. The reason being hasdata works with only one entity at a time. However in your program you have a statechange entity as well.

Comment: If I comment the hasdata, the migration goes through, although I really need to seed my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **class** `IEntityObject` to an **interface**.

Here is a fully working console project that assumes that `StateChange` is some internal class of yours and not a model/entity class:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public interface IEntityObject // <-- changed from `class` to `interface`
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityObject : IEntityObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }   
        
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class MyEntity : EntityObject
    {
        public long OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<StateChange> StateChanges { get; set; }
    }
        
    public class StateChange
    {
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So62865284")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.Ignore(e => e.StateChanges); // <-- ignore your internal class
                    
                    entity.HasData(
                        new MyEntity
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            StateChanges = new List<StateChange>(),
                            OrderId = 2
                        });
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var myEntitiesWithStateChanges = context.MyEntities
                .OrderBy(i => i.Id)
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(myEntitiesWithStateChanges.Count == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In case `StateChange` is supposed to be a model class/entity as well, then you should add a foreign key to it and setup the relationship. This could look like this:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public interface IEntityObject // <-- changed from `class` to `interface`
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityObject : IEntityObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }   
        
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class MyEntity : EntityObject
    {
        public long OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<StateChange> StateChanges { get; set; } = new List<StateChanges>();
    }
        
    public class StateChange : EntityObject
    {
        public int MyEntityId { get; set; } // <-- added FK
        public MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; } // <-- added navigation property
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StateChange> StateChanges { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So62865284")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Added the relationship definition (not really necessary here,
                    // because this would also work by convention).
                    entity.HasMany(e => e.StateChanges)
                        .WithOne(s => s.MyEntity)
                        .HasForeignKey(s => s.MyEntityId);

                    entity.HasData(
                        new MyEntity
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            OrderId = 2
                        });
                });
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<StateChange>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasData(
                        new StateChange
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            MyEntityId = 2,
                        });
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var myEntitiesWithStateChanges = context.MyEntities
                .Include(e => e.StateChanges)
                .OrderBy(i => i.Id)
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(myEntitiesWithStateChanges.Count == 1);
            Debug.Assert(myEntitiesWithStateChanges[0].StateChanges.Count == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer provided by lauxjpn. Adding in my two cents on explaining why it is so.

The *'HasData'* method does not work well with entities when there are relationships defined between them. Please note that *'HasData'* takes in parameters equivalent to the columns created in a table.

So as per the entity design in question, the table created for `MyEntity` object will not contain the `StateChange` entity relation data. In fact the `StateChange` entity will have a `MyEntityId` column to refer to the `Entity` object Id in the form of a foreign key.

In order to add the seed data, you have to call in *'HasData'* for both entities by making use of anonymous type (used if entity properties and table columns do not match) based upon the table columns generated.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasData(
            new
            {
                Id = 1,
                OrderId = 2,
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StateChange>().HasData(
            new
            {
                MyEntityId = 1,
                //Fill in remaining properties of State Change
            });
```

More information on data seeding using *'HasData'* can be found on microsoft docs website.

[data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)